# Change injection payload in SQLmap

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I know you can change parameters and all, but can you change the payload that you’re sending? Like if I wanted to send a payload that would put a txt in someone’s database, is that possible? I’m new to SQLi and have a lot to learn.

Comment: Are you sure sqlmap can write to the database?

Comment: have you read the sqlmap documentation?

Comment: That’s a good point. I think it can, but only rare cases. Can you recommend a different tool for writing?

Comment: once you know how to inject using SQLmap, then you can craft the payloads manually

Comment: Well, `sqlmap` has an `--sql-query` parameter, so you can execute arbitrary statements (if the injection point allows it).